# How to perform a two column split by linking your data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My db is on SQL server

I have a situation where I have a column that brings me the phase of my card and a column that brings me the date that this card entered the phase, but they are in the format of an "Array". How can I link the phase name with its entry date via query?

| card_id | phase_history | firstTimeIn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8837 | [Start, Compliance, Contact, Down] | [2022-08-11T13:44:24+00:00, 2022-08-11T13:44:25+00:00, 2022-08-25T17:37:19+00:00, 2022-08-11T13:44:26+00:00] |
| 6596 | [Start, Compliance, Contact, Down] | [2022-03-11T13:44:24+00:00, 2022-04-11T13:44:25+00:00, 2022-04-25T17:37:19+00:00, 2022-04-11T13:44:26+00:00] |
| 2416 | [Start, Contact, Up] | [2022-08-02T02:22:31+00:00, 2022-08-02T02:22:31+00:00, 2022-08-02T12:13:32+00:00] |
| 5424 | [Start, Compliance, Contact, Lead, Down] | [2022-09-01T12:51:24+00:00, 2022-09-01T12:51:25+00:00, 2022-09-01T13:25:52+00:00, 2022-09-01T12:51:26+00:00, 2022-09-01T16:47:31+00:00] |

I would like it to be like this:

| card_id | phase_history | firstTimeIn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8837 | Start | 2022-08-11T13:44:24+00:00 |
| 8837 | Compliance | 2022-08-11T13:44:25+00:00 |

If anyone has any other suggestions on how to handle this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Storing delimited data violates the basic principles of normalisaiton - however as you have an array then `json` would seem to be the logical approach.

Comment: Use `CROSS APPLY ... STRING_SPLIT ...`. If you're on Azure then you can add an `ordinal` column which makes it easy. If not then, erm, tough.

Comment: If you can't get the ordinal then maybe you can fake it by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ....)` where you look up the start index of the `value` in the original string (and hope that there are no collisions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` to convert the array rows into new rows by the `card_id` column, and use `TRIM` to remove any extraneous brackets and whitespaces.

```
SELECT d.card_id, a.phase_history, a.firstTimeIn
FROM cards d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 
   TRIM('[ ]' FROM c.[value]) AS phase_history, 
   TRIM('[ ]' FROM s.[value]) AS firstTimeIn
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.phase_history, ',', '","'), '"]')) c
   LEFT OUTER JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.firstTimeIn, ',', '","'), '"]')) s 
      ON c.[key] = s.[key]
) a 
WHERE a.phase_history IN ('Start', 'Compliance')
AND card_id = 8837
```

**Result Set:**

| card_id | phase_history | firstTimeIn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8837 | Start | 2022-08-11T13:44:24+00:00 |
| 8837 | Compliance | 2022-08-11T13:44:25+00:00 |

The real solution, *however*, would be to adjust your database design. Storing multiple values in an array format  will cause you a lot of problems in the future. Fixing it now rather than later will prevent future headaches.

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yEGssKaq).